# How to use grep to search for a word recursively in all directories named /src and only *.js files

Tags: grep

In a react project, I want to search for the case insensitive word "tolowercase" in all /src directories and only search in *.js files.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
grep -RHlie tolowercase --include '*.js' /src
```

The options are elaborated on from running `man grep`:

```
     -R, -r, --recursive
             Recursively search subdirectories listed.
     -H      Always print filename headers with output lines.
     -l, --files-with-matches
             Only the names of files containing selected lines are written to
             standard output.  grep will only search a file until a match has
             been found, making searches potentially less expensive.  Path-
             names are listed once per file searched.  If the standard input
             is searched, the string ``(standard input)'' is written.
     -i, --ignore-case
             Perform case insensitive matching.  By default, grep is case sen-
             sitive.
     -e pattern, --regexp=pattern
             Specify a pattern used during the search of the input: an input
             line is selected if it matches any of the specified patterns.
             This option is most useful when multiple -e options are used to
             specify multiple patterns, or when a pattern begins with a dash
             (`-').
```